# why not display text Required in Html after submit radio button empty?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

1.It delivers when you press the answer in the first question why ?

2.not display text Required in Html after submit radio button empty in span tag.

`<span asp-validation-for="@item.CheckAns" class="text-danger"></span>`

> views/Homecontroller1/Index
> **This is CSHTML**

```
@model List<QuestionCommentViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <h3>@item.OneQuestions.TextQ</h3>

                    @foreach (var r in item.ListChoices)
                    {



                        <input type="radio" id="@r.Id" name="@r.Qid" asp-for="@item.CheckAns" value="@r.TextCh">
                        <label for="@r.Id">@r.TextCh</label><br>

                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.CheckAns" class="text-danger"></span>
                    }

                }
                <input type="submit" value="submit" style="background-color:dodgerblue;Color:white; border-radius:5px; font-weight:bold;" />

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

> model

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Task222SchoolApp.Models;

namespace Task222SchoolApp.Models
{
    public class QuestionCommentViewModel
    {
        public Question OneQuestions { get; set; }
        public IQueryable<Choice> ListChoices { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose Answer.")]
        public virtual string CheckAns { get; set; }


    }
}
```

> `controller`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Task222SchoolApp.Models;


namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
   
    public class HomeController1 : Controller

    {

        private readonly SchoolContext _context;
        public HomeController1(SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: HomeController1
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<QuestionCommentViewModel> QCVM = new List<QuestionCommentViewModel>();

            QCVM= GetQCVM();
          //  Console.WriteLine("qqqqqqq");
         
            return View(QCVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Index(List<QuestionCommentViewModel> QCVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
        private IQueryable<Question> getQustion()
        {
            var one = _context.Questions.Include(q => q.QidNavigation);
           
            
             return one;
        }
         private List<QuestionCommentViewModel> GetQCVM()
         {
            Console.WriteLine("111222222222222222222");
            var ListQuestion = getQustion();

           List<QuestionCommentViewModel> QCVM=new List<QuestionCommentViewModel> ();

            foreach (var item in ListQuestion)
            {
                var ch = _context.Choices.Include(q => q.QidNavigation).Where(q=>q.Qid==item.Id);
                 QCVM.Add(new QuestionCommentViewModel() { OneQuestions = item, ListChoices= ch });
                //  return QCVM;

            }

           
            return QCVM;
    }
   
        // GET: HomeController1/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: HomeController1/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: HomeController1/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: HomeController1/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: HomeController1/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: HomeController1/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: HomeController1/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code like below

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <h3>@item.OneQuestions.TextQ</h3>

                @foreach (var r in item.ListChoices)
                {
                    <input type="radio" id="@r.Id" asp-for="@item.CheckAns" value="@r.TextCh">
                    <label for="@r.Id">@r.TextCh</label><br>

                }
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.CheckAns" class="text-danger"></span>

            }
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: code Has a problem that he selects one option from all entries on a page ؟